# Angular 2 routes with children

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a default route (home) and I want "home" to have childroutes. So that when you go to Home, the homecomponent should load, and when you go to Homes children, a specific childroute should load. But right now my home component loads, but I can't navigate to any of it's children. What am I doing wrong?

This is my core routes:

```
export const coreRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    redirectTo: 'home', 
    pathMatch: 'full' 
  },
  { 
    path: 'home', 
    component: HomeComponent, 
    data: { breadcrumb: 'Home', icon: 'fa-home' }, 
    children: homeChildRoutes 
  }
];
```

and this is my homeChildRoutes:

```
export const homeChildRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    redirectTo: 'home', 
    pathMatch: 'full' 
  },
  { 
    path: 'first-child', 
    component: firstChildComponent, 
    data: { breadcrumb: 'First Child', parent: 'home' } 
  },
  { 
    path: 'second-child', 
    component: secondChildComponent, 
    data: { breadcrumb: 'Second Child', parent: 'home'  } 
  }
];
```

Comment: Do you want to render the HomeComponent and the childComponents in the same router-outlet? It's important to understand that children routes render the content of the child component in the router-outlet of the parent's component. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think so, I'm pretty new to Angular but what I want to achieve is to have the homecomponent to show when you navigate to root, with some content. And then when you navigate to it's children, the childrens content should be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're on `/home` page, HomeComponent is shown

When you're on `/home/first-child` page, firstChildComponent is shown, HomeComponent is hidden

```
// core routes
export const coreRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'home', 
    children: homeChildRoutes
  },
  { 
    path: '', 
    redirectTo: 'home', 
    pathMatch: 'full' 
  },
];

// child routes
export const homeChildRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    data: { breadcrumb: 'Home', icon: 'fa-home' },
  },
  { 
    path: 'first-child', 
    component: firstChildComponent, 
    data: { breadcrumb: 'First Child', parent: 'home' } 
  },
  { 
    path: 'second-child', 
    component: secondChildComponent, 
    data: { breadcrumb: 'Second Child', parent: 'home'  } 
  },
];
```

Comment: Sorry for late answer, this works but I don't see where I did wrong?

Comment: I think you couldn't see child components because there's no <router-outlet> in HomeComponent. Manu Bhardwaj answer is correct as well, but it's up to you which behaviour you prefer: mine where home, child1 or child2 are shown one by one, or Manu Bhardwaj, where child1 or child2 are visible inside of HomeComponent

Answer (score 1):

**Routes can be simplified to this:**

```
export const coreRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'home', 
    component: HomeComponent, 
    data: { breadcrumb: 'Home', icon: 'fa-home' }, 
    children: [
      { 
         path: '', 
         redirectTo: 'home', 
         pathMatch: 'full' 
      },
      { 
        path: 'first-child', 
        component: firstChildComponent, 
        data: { breadcrumb: 'First Child', parent: 'home' } 
      },
      { 
        path: 'second-child', 
        component: secondChildComponent, 
        data: { breadcrumb: 'Second Child', parent: 'home'  } 
      }
    ] 
  },
  ,
 { 
    path: '', 
    redirectTo: 'home', 
    pathMatch: 'full' 
 }
];
```

**Make sure your HomeComponent has a router-outlet. Or else your child component will not be visible.**

Refer [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bcnzcv) for code.